# Разбор HTML страницы

Tags: c#, html, htmlagilitypack

Помогите с разбором HTML страниц! В программе есть возможность задавать комментарии в виде HTML страницы. Внутри HTML лежит то, что туда напихал пользователь - в основном это текст, таблицы, списки. Например такое:

```html
<BODY>
<P>Комментарий</P>
<P>1.</P>
<P>
 <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=249 border=1>
 <COLGROUP>
 <COL span=3 width=83>
 <TBODY>
  <TR height=20>
   <TD class=xl66 height=20 width=83>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;1:1</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl64 width=83>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;1:2</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl65 width=83>
    <FONT face=Calibri>1:3&nbsp;</FONT>
   </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR height=20>
   <TD class=xl67 height=20>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;2:1</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl63>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;2:2</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl63>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;2:3</FONT>
   </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR height=20>
   <TD class=xl63 height=20>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl63>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl63>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
   </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR height=20>
   <TD class=xl63 height=20>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
   </TD>
   <TD class=xl63>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
   <TD class=xl63>
    <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
   </TD>
  </TR>
 </TBODY>
 </TABLE>&nbsp;
</P>
<P>2.</P>
<P>
 <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=192 border=1>
  <COLGROUP>
  <COL span=3 width=64>
  <TBODY>
   <TR height=20>
    <TD class=xl66 height=40 rowSpan=2 width=64>
     <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;1:1</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD class=xl64 width=128 colSpan=2>
     <FONT face=Calibri>1:2</FONT>
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR height=20>
    <TD class=xl63 height=20>
     <FONT face=Calibri>2:2</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD class=xl63>
     <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;2:3</FONT>
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR style="HEIGHT: 15pt" height=20>
    <TD class=xl63 height=20>
     <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;3:1</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD class=xl63>
     <FONT face=Calibri>3:2</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD class=xl63>
     <FONT face=Calibri>3:3</FONT>
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR height=20>
    <TD class=xl63 height=20>
     <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD class=xl63>
     <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD class=xl63>
     <FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT>
    </TD>
   </TR>
  </TBODY>
 </TABLE>
</P>
<P>3.</P>
<P>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=256 border=1>
<COLGROUP>
<COL span=4 width=64>
<TBODY>
<TR height=20>
<TD class=xl63 height=20 width=64 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>1</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 width=64 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>2</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 width=64 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>3</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 width=64 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>4</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR height=20>
<TD class=xl63 height=20 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>1</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT color=#ff8000 face=Calibri>2</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right>
<P align=center><FONT color=#ff8000 face=Calibri>3</FONT></P></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT color=#ff8000 face=Calibri>4</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR height=20>
<TD class=xl63 height=20 align=right><FONT color=#ff8000 face=Calibri>1</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT color=#ff8000 face=Calibri>2</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>3</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>4</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR style="HEIGHT: 15pt" height=20>
<TD class=xl63 height=20 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>1</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>2</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right>
<P align=center><FONT face=Calibri>3</FONT></P></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>4</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR height=20>
<TD class=xl63 height=20 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>1</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>2</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>3</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>4</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR height=20>
<TD class=xl63 height=20 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>1</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>2</FONT></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right>
<P align=center><FONT face=Calibri>3</FONT></P></TD>
<TD class=xl63 align=right><FONT face=Calibri>4</FONT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></P>
<P>&nbsp;4.</P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; mso-fareast-font-family: Symbol; mso-bidi-font-family: Symbol; mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">·<SPAN style='FONT: 7pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT face=Calibri>Ntcn 1<?xml:namespace prefix = "o" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; mso-fareast-font-family: Symbol; mso-bidi-font-family: Symbol; mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">·<SPAN style='FONT: 7pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT face=Calibri>Ntcn 2<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 8pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; mso-fareast-font-family: Symbol; mso-bidi-font-family: Symbol; mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">·<SPAN style='FONT: 7pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT face=Calibri>Ntcn 3<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 8pt"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><o:p><FONT face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-latin"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore"><FONT face=Calibri>1.</FONT><SPAN style='FONT: 7pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT face=Calibri>Ntcn 1<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-latin"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore"><FONT face=Calibri>2.</FONT><SPAN style='FONT: 7pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT face=Calibri>Ntcn 2<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 8pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-latin"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore"><FONT face=Calibri>3.</FONT><SPAN style='FONT: 7pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT face=Calibri>Ntcn 3</FONT></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 8pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2">&nbsp;</P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 8pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2">5.</P>
<P class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 8pt 36pt; TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; mso-list: l1 level1 lfo2">&nbsp;</P>
</BODY>
```

Каждый такой HTML комментарий произвольный и не содержит какой-либо заранее заданной структуры.
Мне необходимо пройтись по порядку по всей странице и  определить, какие блоки за какими следуют, т.е. определить в каком порядке следуют элементы, а затем на основе этих данных сформировать свое представление для вывода на печать. Из-за того, что сам комментарий создается пользователем то в разметке есть места не по стандарту - в примере первая таблица лежит внутри тэга `<p>`, в третьей таблице в ячейках `<td>` находится тэг `<p>`. Таблицы создаются в Word/Excel и копируются оттуда в комментарии и получаются такими кривыми, списки тоже сделаны отдельными тэгами `<p>`.
Я бы хотел получить что-то подобное:

1. Текст (Комментарий)
2. Текст (1.)
3. Таблица
4. Текст (2.)
5. Таблица
6. Текст (3.)
7. Таблица
8. Текст (4.)
9. Список (1.)
10. Список (2.)
11. и т.д.

Comment: Ок, а в чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что не получается получить желаемое, из-за HTML не по стандарту, в <p> не может лежать <table>, например. И получается, что внтури текста у меня приходит таблица, а я бы хотел просто таблицу.

Comment: пользователь может сам вставлять разметку HTML в комментарии или разметка добавляется программно? Если программно - то полученная разметка валидна с точки зрения XML (забудем на время про стандарты HTML)? Если валидна как XML то можно прикрутить хитрую XSLT и получить валидный HTML, вроде ни чего не перепутал, но без ответов на первые 2 вопроса это только предположение

Comment: Для ввода комментария используется вот эта штука https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WinForms-HTML-Editor-01dbce1a, если в ворде/екселе создать текст, таблицы и вставить в этот компонент - получаем HTML, доступа к разметке у пользователя нет.

Answer (score 1):

Найдите порт этого чуда на C# и научитесь с ним работать: [HTML Tidy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy). Вроде много чего еще лежит в NuGet по запросу Tidy или, к примеру, можете попробовать библиотеки из [этих ответов на EN:SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002346/c-sharp-version-of-html-tidy).  Я думаю это максимум, что можно без велосипедов выжать из неправильной разметки.

Comment: Пробовал, и действительно в некоторых моментах он отрабатывает - тэг <p> вокруг таблицы удаляет, а вот  <td> <p> text </p> </td> оставляет без изменений. И основная беда с этот библиотечкой под .Net - нет описаний методов и документации, а из названий методов понятнее не становится.

Comment: @Nova, учитывая, что это портированная библиотека, то по идее можно взять документацию с офф. сайта: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/. Кстати, там же лежит .NET wrapper.